# Does Django Cache Clear Itself After Expiration

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I am currently working with Memcache and Django to cache data requested from an external API, so I don't overwhelm their servers. Currently my code looks like this:

```
# CACHE CURRENT PRICE
cache_key_price = str(stock.id)+'_price' # needs to be unique
cache_key_change = str(stock.id)+'_change'
cache_keychange_pct = str(stock.id)+'_changePct'

cache_time = 60 * 5 # time in seconds for cache to be valid
price_data = cache.get(cache_key_price) # returns None if no key-value pair
change_data = cache.get(cache_key_change) # returns None if no key-value pair
changePct_data = cache.get(cache_keychange_pct) # returns None if no key-value pair

if not price_data:
    delayed_price, change, changePct = get_quote(stock.ticker)

    price_data = delayed_price
    change_data = change
    changePct_data = changePct

cache.set(cache_key_price, price_data, cache_time)
cache.set(cache_key_change, change_data, cache_time)
cache.set(cache_keychange_pct, changePct_data, cache_time)

context_dict['delayed_price'] = cache.get(cache_key_price)
context_dict['change'] = cache.get(cache_key_change)
context_dict['changePct'] = cache.get(cache_keychange_pct)
```

I'm a bit new to caching and I am curious if after 5 mins the cache will clear itself and `data` will return None triggering the `if not data:` bit of code to get updated data.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The code looks ok. Are you getting any errors or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Sorry I just updated a second ago, would you mind taking a look at it again. No weird behavior, but I'm a noob at caching and this is my first live project using it, so I just want to make sure.

Comment: You should indent the 3 statements `cache.ser(...)`; they should only be run inside the `if not price_data:`. Other than that the code should work; just try it out.

Comment: Just to clarify, `cache.set()` should only run when `if not price_data:` is triggered. And `if not price_data` is triggered when the cache expires after 5 mins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simplified version of your code (with just 1 key, not all 3 keys); you extend this to suit your needs.

I made 2 changes: first, the statement `cache.set(..)` needs to be inside the `if not price_data:` block, so that it is only run when the cache is empty (or expired).

Second, you should use the variable `price_data` to load into the context; so you don't need to call `cache.get(..)` a second time.

```
cache_key_price = str(stock.id)+'_price' # needs to be unique
cache_time = 60 * 5 # time in seconds for cache to be valid
price_data = cache.get(cache_key_price) # returns None if no key-value pair

if not price_data:
    delayed_price, change, changePct = get_quote(stock.ticker)
    price_data = delayed_price
    cache.set(cache_key_price, price_data, cache_time)

context_dict['delayed_price'] = price_data
```